# How do I add a Cache-Control HTTP header to images I upload to Amazon S3?

Tags: c#, web-services, amazon-s3

I think I'm probably just missing something in the docs here, but how do I specify that images I upload to S3 have a Cache-Control header when requested?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269840/is-it-possible-to-change-headers-on-an-s3-object-without-downloading-the-entire-o/270066) seems to suggest you can do it by adding metadata, but the example isn't too clear. Can anyone point me to a code sample or some documentation of how I would do this in C# please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that this is possible using the REST API for S3, but not using the SOAP methods. So the answer for me is just 'no' - unless we rewrite all our code to use the REST API.

[See this AWS Support Forum post](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=67395).

Answer (score 7):

For those reading this question more recently, you can use the [TransferUtilityUploadRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityUploadRequest.htm)'s **Headers.CacheControl** property (Note: At the time of writing the AWS documentation doesn't make it obvious that this is an available property).

eg

```
// Make the upload request with the required cache and header parameters
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
   BucketName = BucketName,
   FilePath = fileName,
   StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
   Key = keyName,
   CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
   ContentType = contentType,
};

fileTransferUtilityRequest.Headers.CacheControl = "max-age=604800";
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(...);
fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
```