# How to change metadata on an object in Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

If you have already uploaded an object to an Amazon S3 bucket, how do you change the metadata using the API? It is possible to do this in the AWS Management Console, but it is not clear how it could be done programmatically. Specifically, I'm using the boto API in Python and from reading the source it is clear that using key.set_metadata only works *before* the object is created as it just effects a local dictionary.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It appears you need to overwrite the object with itself, using a "PUT Object (Copy)" with an `x-amz-metadata-directive: REPLACE` header in addition to the metadata. In boto, this can be done like this:

```
k = k.copy(k.bucket.name, k.name, {'myKey':'myValue'}, preserve_acl=True)
```

Note that any metadata you do not include in the old dictionary will be dropped. So to preserve old attributes you'll need to do something like:

```
k.metadata.update({'myKey':'myValue'})
k2 = k.copy(k.bucket.name, k.name, k.metadata, preserve_acl=True)
k2.metadata = k.metadata    # boto gives back an object without *any* metadata
k = k2;
```

I almost missed this solution, which is hinted at in the intro to an incorrectly-titled question that's actually about a different problem than this question: [Change Content-Disposition of existing S3 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613792/amazon-s3-add-metadata-to-existing-key)

Comment: I don't see in the second code example where the union between old and new metadata is taking place.  When I execute the code, the metadata for the object gets overwritten with the latest metadata.

Comment: Seems to work, but the new key loses the Content-Type, which is really bad when using S3 to serve web images.

Comment: For those of you using the AWS SDK you need to use [AmazonS3Client.copyObject method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#copyObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest))

Comment: Does it copying the content of the key or only the metadata?
Copying the whole key takes time, and decrease the efficiency, right?

Comment: This also seems to replace the infamous multipart ETag with a regular MD5 of the entire file - which kills two birds with one stone for me. The boto3 package does not seem to do this incidentally. In summary: GREAT +1 :)

Comment: Actually - I stand corrected - boto3's s3 package has `client.copy_object` which creates an MD5 ETag - at least with the 150MB objects I tested. However, you cannot "copy over" an existing object, unlike `Key.copy` above.

Answer (score 12):

In order to set metadata on S3 files,just don't provide target location as only source information is enough to set metadata.

```
final ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.addUserMetadata(metadataKey, value);
final CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, bucketName, keyName)
  .withSourceBucketName(bucketName)
  .withSourceKey(keyName)
  .withNewObjectMetadata(metadata);

s3.copyObject(request);`
```

Comment: The question asked for Python, but this was the only answer using the Java SDK that I've been able to find on SO. Thanks!

Comment: We are able to put tag on file of any size but not sure, if metadata on heavy file issue is fixed or not.

Answer (score 8):

If you want your metadata stored remotely use `set_remote_metadata`

Example:
`key.set_remote_metadata({'to_be': 'added'}, ['key', 'to', 'delete'], {True/False})`

Implementation is here:
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/66b360449812d857b4ec6a9834a752825e1e7603/boto/s3/key.py#L1875

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the easiest way to do what @natevw's answer describes. It does the same thing under the hood. Note that `metadata_minus` and `preserve_acl` are required.

Comment: key.set_metadata() works too (though it just replace the existing metadata). set_remote_metadata() supports addition and deleting with existing metadata.  This should be the correct answer, compare with the current top answer.

Comment: A note for anyone who comes here looking nowadays: this is no longer possible in boto3.  Be sure to refine your search for boto3.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the metadata without re-uloading the object by using the copy command. See this question: [Is it possible to change headers on an S3 object without downloading the entire object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269840/is-it-possible-to-change-headers-on-an-s3-object-without-downloading-the-entire)

Answer (score 1):

For the first answer it's a good idea to include the original content type in the metadata, for example:

```
key.set_metadata('Content-Type', key.content_type)
```

Comment: Been a while since I've used it, but I'm pretty sure that's among the things passing the original `k.metadata` field on the copy accomplishes.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, You can copy object to the same location. 
Here metadata will not copy while copying an Object. 
You have to get metadata of original and set to copy request. 
This method is more recommended to insert or update metadata of an Amazon S3 object

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = amazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, fileKey);
ObjectMetadata metadataCopy = new ObjectMetadata();
metadataCopy.addUserMetadata("yourKey", "updateValue");
metadataCopy.addUserMetadata("otherKey", "newValue");
metadataCopy.addUserMetadata("existingKey", metadata.getUserMetaDataOf("existingValue"));

CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey, bucketName, fileKey)
      .withSourceBucketName(bucketName)
      .withSourceKey(fileKey)
      .withNewObjectMetadata(metadataCopy);

amazonS3Client.copyObject(request);
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the code that worked for me.   I'm using aws-java-sdk-s3 version 1.10.15

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType(fileExtension.getMediaType());

s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, tempFile)
                    .withMetadata(metadata));
```