# Using boto to force the browser to show the image instead of downloading it?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have the following image file:

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/008378019847.jpg

If you click on the link, it will force a download to your browser. How would I get this file instead to open in the browser, such as how the following link does? https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-r-NV4YMr0Gc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFvE/BcDknpxfm7M/s120-c/photo.jpg

I would like to use `boto` in a bulk operation to accomplish this.

Comment: Are they all .jpg's?

Comment: Yes, they are all jpegs.

Comment: Awesome, I think I have your answer. Just a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I visit your image with Chrome's network inspector on, I see `application/octet-stream` as the `content-type`.

I think you need to specify the `content-type` to be a `image/jpeg`. I tested this on an S3 bucket and this fixed the 'problem' induced by it being an `application/octet-stream`.

I don't know how to do bulk operations with boto, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754439/1849664) shows how to do it on a single object. You just want to change the `content-type` metadata to be `image/jpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this before sending the image to s3

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket("your-bucket")
key = bucket.new_key("your-key")
key.content_type = "image/jpeg"
key.set_contents_from_string("content")
key.make_public()
```