# Setting metadata on S3 multipart upload

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, boto

I'd like to upload a file to S3 in parts, and set some metadata on the file. I'm using boto to interact with S3. I'm able to set metadata with single-operation uploads like so:

Is there a way to set metadata with a multipart upload? I've tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754383/how-to-change-metadata-on-an-object-in-amazon-s3) of copying the key to change the metadata, but it fails with the error: `InvalidRequest: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: <size>`

I've also tried doing the following:

```
key = bucket.create_key(key_name)
key.set_metadata('some-key', 'value')
<multipart upload>
```

...but the multipart upload overwrites the metadata.

I'm using code [similar to this](https://bcbio.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/parallel-upload-to-amazon-s3-with-python-boto-and-multiprocessing/) to do the multipart upload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I just found the answer:

Per [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html):

> If you want to provide any metadata describing the object being uploaded, you must provide it in the request to initiate multipart upload.

So in `boto`, the metadata can be set in the `initiate_multipart_upload` call. [Docs here.](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.initiate_multipart_upload)

Comment: How can I use SSE-KMS along with multipart upload?
Complete question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328843/s3-multipart-upload-with-sse-kms

Answer (score 2):

Faced such issue earlier today and discovered that there is no information on how to do that right.
The code example on how we solved that issue provided below.

```
        $uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, $source, [
        'bucket' => $bucketName,
        'key' => $filename,
        'before_initiate' => function (\Aws\Command $command) {
            $command['ContentType'] = 'application/octet-stream';
            $command['ContentDisposition'] = 'attachment';
        },
    ]);
```

Unfortunately, documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html#customizing-a-multipart-upload doesn't make it clear and easy to understand that if you'd like to provide alternative meta data with multipart upload you have to go this way.

I hope that will help.